# Prevent (non-bootstrap) Modal Popup from immediately closing after button submit, and display messages

Tags: javascript, button, woocommerce, modal-dialog, submit

I have created a modal popup to login (and also retrieve password) picking on some hints from other posts. It works fine except that when I submit the login button it immediately closes the modal, even if there is a message displayed. One can see that the message was displayed by opening the popup again:

[image]

The intention is obviously not to have the popup close immediately when there is any kind of message, otherwise the client doesn't have the chance to see it.

I have searched for this problem in this website and others but only saw solutions that seem to imply bootstrap modals and other solutions that do not fit my case. Any help is highly appreciated.

My code below:

```js
//JAVASCRIPT
// Get the modal
                var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn_login_popup");

                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];
                
                var pasw = document.getElementById("retrieve_pasw");
                var pasw_form = document.getElementById("modal-body_b");
                
                // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
                if (btn2) {
                    btn2.onclick = function() {
                        modal2.style.display = "block";
                    }
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span2.onclick = function(event) {
                    modal2.style.display = "none";
                }

                pasw.onclick = function(event) {
                    pasw_form.style.display = "block";
                }
```

```html
<!-- HTML
<!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content2">
                    <div class="modal-header_a">
                        <?php echo '<h2>' . $header_content . '</h2>';?>
                        <span class="close2"></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
                    <div class="modal-body_a">
                        
                        <form action="" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">
                            
                            <?php echo __('Please insert your username/email and your password to login:', 'woocommerce_php'); ?>
                            
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

                   <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide" 
                    <label for="username"><?php _e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username"
                    value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ) : ''; ?>" autofocus required />
                   </p>
                   <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" required />
                   </p>

                   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

                   <p class="form-row">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox inline">
                     <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" />
                     <span><?php _e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                    </label>
                   </p>

                   <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                    <button type="button" id="retrieve_pasw" class="retrieve_pasw" href=""><?php _e( 'Forgot password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                   </p>

                   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>
                        </form> 
      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi! It would help to post the HMTL result without the PHP code, CSS rules and entire JS involved.

Comment: I will take out the CSS. The rest I believe is important for you guys to figure out a solution ...

Comment: CSS gone ... Lighter now. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't write that correctly, sorry. I meant to take out PHP code, but add the concerning CSS/JS rules to figure out what's not working. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: CSS is not necessary, just filling space there.

Comment: I took out some HTML code that is doing more of the same, so not necessary for our purposes here. As for javascript, I have it all there, on the first block where i say 'JAVASCRIPT'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it !! After looking a lot around and thinking about it.

First we must include a variable to check whether there are (error) messages in the buffer to be displayed. If so, then just let them print to screen and force the reopening of the modal.

So in the first step, it will suffice to replace the line where I had

```html
<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
```

with the following php:

```html
<?php 
  ob_start();
  wc_print_notices();
  $messages = ob_get_contents();
?>
```

The second step implies some javascript to make sure that when the variable $messages is not empty, we force the modal to stay open.

```js
var messages_bool = "<?php echo !empty($messages); ?>";
if (messages_bool) {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}
```

Finally, we must make sure that if the user closes the modal and then reopens it, that the message is no longer there ...

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-error");
for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

This is working fine in my website.